# How to solve this ODE by DSolve

Tags: differential-equations

I try to solve this second order ODE:
$$\frac{ y'(x)}{3 x}+y''(x)+y(x)^3=0$$
with some of the following boundary conditions:

- $y'=0 , y=0$

My question is, how to solve this problem ?
I have tried
`sol=DSolve[{y''[x] + (1/(3x ))y'[x] + y[x]^3 == 0,y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0},y,x]`

Unfortunately, DSolve not work

Comment: It could just be that no solution exists.  If $y \propto x^\alpha$ to leading order in the neighborhood of $x = 0$, it's not too hard to show that you must have either $\alpha = -1$, $\alpha = 0$, or $\alpha = \frac{2}{3}$.  None of these options can satisfy both $y \to 0$ and $y' \to 0$ as $x \to 0$.

Comment: well, there is always the trivial solution $y(x)=0$ which satisfies the ODE and the BC. But I do not think there is nontrivial solution also. Maple can't solve it either.

Comment: I tried to reewrite the ode, making a system of equations and solve,  but it not work's too.

Comment: `NDSolve` produces   zero solution.